# infinite world creation with libgdx

Tags: libgdx

I am a newbie and a little lost. Which classes or tools do you recommend to create an infinite libgdx game world with collision detected available, so that the player can walk on it? The concept is shown in the images below. The camera (phone screen) moves around the world in a non-linear fashion(on a boundary between green and white in this image), tracking the character. All I need is some place to start, I will be good from there on.

[image]

[image]

EDIT: Basically the problem is to create an infinite world, perhaps self generating is a better world, with collision detection enabled. I have tried nothing because I don't even know where to start. I only need to be directed in the right direction on this.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to give you a few keywords to search for:

- Infinite world: Procedural generation
- libGDX collision detection:

  - Box2D or bullet (physics engines inside libGDX)
  - libGDX provides also `Circle` or `Rectangle` to check for overlapping
- Camera tracking: `ViewPort`, Culling